# Unity (Ubuntu) option is missing from login menu

Tags: 11.10, unity, login

After purging and reinstalling Nautilus, Unity is missing and everything defaults to GNOME Classic. The Unity (Ubuntu) option at login is even missing. The Unity plugin is still ticked in `ccsm`. If I run `unity --replace` the terminal starts Unity and I get the dash and Unity panel but still have the bottom GNOME panel. If I log out and back in everything is back to GNOME Classic. It seems the only way I can run Unity is by running `unity --replace` in the terminal.

Is there a way to get things back to normal without a clean install?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you removed some packages that depend on Nautilus but did not reinstall them.

Make sure that the package `ubuntu-desktop` is installed, for example by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

in a terminal.